# Finding a sub-array where every pair has sum greater than a given K

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have been given an array A of integers. Now I have to found out a sub-array(a sub-sequence of original array) where sum of every pair is greater than or equal to a pre-defined K.

What I thought :-

- Will sort the array in O(nlgn) or O(n) depending upon range of values in array.
- Find out i in sorted array such that `sorted[i] + sorted[i+1]>=k`
- Set max to `sorted[i]`
- Traverse the original array to delete all value smaller than max, which is the required sub-sequence

Repeat the above for all the elements of the array.

Running Time :- `O(nlgn)`

Is the solution optimal ? Can we further improve it ?

Example :-

```
-10 -100 5 2 4 7 10 23 81 5 25
```

Sorted Array

```
-100 -10 2 4 5 5 7 10 23 25 81
```

Let `K = 20`

Sub Array : -

10 23 25 81

Had the question been to find out longest sub-array, algorithm suggested by alestanis in the answers would work fine :)

Comment: Can you give an example of array A and resulting sub-array? From what I see, you just need to be sure that sum of the lowest two elements of the resulting array should be greater than or equal to K.

Comment: @raina77ow Example added

Comment: Your cutoff should be at 10, and the subarray should be 10, ..., 81

Comment: I think, once you have ordered the array, in step 2, you need to find the lowest index `i` such that `array[i] + array[i+1] >= K`

Comment: To me the term sub-array means sorting the array will break the solution. Perhaps you're looking for a subset of the elements in the array. Will any subset do, or do you need the largest, or the first, or the smallest, or something else? Each of those is a significantly different problem...

Comment: Upvoted the comments I agree with. I just don't understand why sub-array given by you is suitable; first I think that sum of each opposite elements should be not less than K, but then `5+10` breaks it...

Comment: sorry there were issues with example given

Comment: I think @twalberg 's question has to be answered before you can get a good answer: do you need a subarray (i.e. a contiguous set of elements from the original array), or a subset (i.e. any combination of elements from the array)? If it's the latter, do you need the largest such subset?

Comment: @twalberg Lets assume that it has to a sub-sequence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a fairly simple solution.

```
>>> def f(A, k):
...     solution = [item for item in A if 2*item >= k]
...     m = min(solution)
...     for item in A:
...         if item + m >= k and 2*item < k:
...             solution.append(item)
...             break
...     return solution
...
>>> f([-10, -100, 5, 2, 4, 7, 10, 23, 81, 5, 25], 20)
[10, 23, 81, 25]
>>>
```

Comment: Nice solution. Btw, how that '2*item>=k' came into picture ? Whats the logic ?

Comment: what about `f([1, 2], 3)`? The correct output is [1, 2], but your algorithm will give [1].

Comment: it does give [1,2]. @prashant there can only be one item in the solution less than half k.

Comment: @robertking my bad, missed the part, where `solution` is inited. Good job!

Comment: your solution will give list of all integer from the array out of which sum of any two is more than or equal to given k and that list may not be a **subsequence**

Comment: Look at comment clarifications, I think he just wants numbers from the array. This is what he asked for. He misused the word "subsequence and sub-array". It wasn't what he wanted.

Comment: are [5,23,81,25], [7,23,81,25] part of solution?

Comment: They are valid solutions but my function doesn't find them it only finds one. If you want all solutions, you could create two heapq's. One heapq contains numbers >= 2*k, the other contains numbers < 2*k. Each time you pop a small number from one heapq, check it against the smallest number in the other heapq to see if it adds to above k. If not, pop from the other heapq, and check. Since we are taking numbers from biggest to smallest in one heapq, and smallest to largest in the other heapq, we keep going until there are no more solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a slightly different approach, hinted at by one of the earlier comments and similar to the answer by alestanis, but slightly different, in that it doesn't depend on splitting arrays. It makes a single pass through the array (although that doesn't guarantee O(N) ), and just needs to track the two minimum values as well as the start and end point of the subsequence being considered.

For a contiguous subsequence to have all possible pairs sum to 20, the sum of the two least elements must be >= 20. So start by considering subsequent pairs of elements (`array[0]` and `array[1]` to start). If they don't sum to 20 or more, then move on to `array[1]` and `array[2]`. If they add up to 20 or more, then expand the right hand endpoint by one. If the new element is greater than the other two, then it will sum to 20 or greater with anything already in the subsequence, and you can expand the right hand again. If it's less, then you need to pick the two least elements with a couple comparisons, and if the two new least elements now don't sum to 20 or more, then remove the element you've just added from the subsequence, and note this particular subsequence, then start over with the second and third elements of the existing subsequence. At the end, you will in general have a list of subsequences that fit the constraints, and it should be easy to pick the first or largest or whatever you need.

Example, using the sequence you listed:

```
-10 -100 5 2 4 7 10 23 81 5 25
```

Start with `-10, -100`. They don't sum to 20, so move right one to `-100, 5`. Again, these don't sum to 20, so continue. The first pair that does sum to 20 is `10, 23`. So now, we expand the range to `10, 23, 81`. 81 is greater than both the two minimums, so we expand again, to `10, 23, 81, 5`. 5 is less than both 10 and 23, so the new minimums are 5 and 10, which don't sum to 20, so adding 5 was a mistake and we need to backtrack. We find `10, 23, 81` is one such subsequence. Next we continue with `23, 81`, which will lead us to the subsequence `23, 81, 5, 25`, which meets the criteria as well.

So, at the end, we have four possible subsequences that meet the critieria - `10, 23, 81`, `23, 81, 5, 25`, `81, 5, 25`, and `5, 25`. The last two could be pruned by not finding additional solutions once we have one that includes the last element in the original list, which would leave just the first two possibilities. From there we can pick either the first or the longest.

Comment: Complexity can too much for this solution.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you **can't** sort your set. I think that part of the problem is to find sub-arrays of the original array given as input.

This can be solved using some recursion:

1. Find the two minimums of your array, `m1` and `m2`
2. If `m1 + m2 < K` then split your array into at most two smaller arrays that don't contain `m1` and `m2` simultaneously. If indexes for `m1` and `m2` are `i` and `j` with `i<j` then subarrays are `[O, j-1]` and `[i+1, n]`.
   Repeat from step 1.
3. If `m1 + m2 >= K` then your current array is a feasible solution to your problem: return its length.
4. Add some **pruning** to discard useless arrays

Let's apply this on your example:

```
Initialize max = 0;
A1 = -10* -100* 5 2 4 7 10 23 81 5 25
```

Its two minimums are -10 and -100. Split the array around these values, which gives us only one array (we're lucky!)

```
A2 = 5 2* 4* 7 10 23 81 5 25
```

The two minimums of `A2` are 2 and 4. We split into

```
A3_1 = 5* 4*   and    A3_2 = 2* 7 10 23 81 5* 25
```

This continues with the following iterations:

```
A3_1 discarded    
A3_2 becomes A4_1 = 2* 7* 10 23 81    A4_2 = 7* 10 23 81 5* 25

A5_1 = 7* 10* 23 81
A5_2 = 7* 10* 23 81        -> Duplicate, discarded
A5_3 = 10* 23 81 5* 25

A6_1 = 10* 23* 81          -> Yay! update max = 3
A6_2 = 10* 23* 81          -> Length <= max. Discarded
A6_3 = 23 81 5* 25         -> Yay! update max = 4
```

In this example, I pruned the search space by:

- Eliminating duplicate subsets (this can be done by storing them in a set for instance)
- Discarding subarrays shorter or equal to the current max length known

This algorithm has a complexity of:

- O(nlogn) average,
- O(n^2) worst case. This happens when array is sorted and minimums are always on one of the sides of the array, so the array can't be split into smaller subarrays (like the first iteration of the example).

Comment: What do you mean by you can't sort ? Do you mean, the sequence of number matters ?

Comment: If you sort, the subarrays you find are **not** subarrays of the original array. They're just sets of randomly-placed elements of your original array. In your example, subarray `10 23 25 81` **does not** belong to original array.

Comment: I didn't get the way you are splitting the array at every step

Comment: Also analyze the running time of your algorithm. Is it better than O(nlogn) ? I can still get the answer by traversing my original array while still using comparison via sorted array

Comment: As I said, you can't sort and sorting doesn't give you an answer. So your O(nlogn) complexity can't apply.

Comment: Splitting is done like this: if your minimums are at index i and j, split your array into two sub-arrays: indexes [0; j-1] and indexes [i+1; n]

Comment: Please, why the downvote? My answer is complete, detailed, well formatted and correct.

Comment: I have editted my question. It always runs in O(nlogn). Btw, I have not down-voted !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18420/discussion-between-alestanis-and-prashant-singh)

Comment: What will be the terminating criteria of the splitting process ?

Comment: @alestanis I upvoted because it's a nice solution for finding the largest sub-array, Unfortunately Prashant actually wants the largest "sub-set" (his question has the wording wrong). My solution was just a matter of including all numbers above k/2 and one number below k/2

Comment: @robertking the original question was about a sub-array. the question was edited afterwards (but look at the unchanged title) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
void sub_array(int ar[],int n,int val)
{
    int max=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(ar[max]<ar[i])
            max=i;
    }
    int b[n];
    max=ar[max];
    int p=0;
    int min=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(ar[i]+max>val)
        {
            b[p]=ar[i];
            if(ar[i]<max)
            {   
                min=p;
                max=ar[i];
            }
            p++;
        }
        else
        {
            if(ar[i]>max)
            {
                max=ar[i];
                b[min]=ar[i];
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<p;i++)
    {
        cout<<b[i]<< "  " ;
    }
}
```